# How to write a specific data from one Excel sheet to another sheet through script?

Tags: excel, vba

Please find the below details,

```
INPUT OUTPUT
2   8
6   7
0   0
0   0
55  88
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
75  94
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
30  30
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
45  45
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
14  106
13  13
```

I have the above data in sheet1, I want to write data sum of the each in column in sheet2.

Comment: Does each number above represent the value of a row/column?

Comment: `SUM(A2, B2)` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to add INPUT(sheet 1) and OUTPUT(sheet 1) and display the result on column 1(sheet 2)? If so, try this;

```
Private Sub add()

Dim i As Integer

i = 2

Do Until Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) = ""

       Sheet2.Cells(i, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) + Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)

i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

I assumed that INPUT is on column 1 and OUTPUT is on column 2.